# Why Isnt this server accesible from web?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, networking

contents of serverside.py

```
    import socket               
    s = socket.socket()        
    host = "127.0.0.1" 
    port = 9000       
    s.bind((host, port))       

    s.listen(5)           
    while True:
       c, addr = s.accept()   
       print 'Got connection from', addr
       c.send('Thank you for connecting')
       c.close()
```

now when i open cmd and type 
        telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
The server works perfectly fine.

cmd shows display - Thank you for connecting

and shell shows display - Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 54578)

But when I connect this over The WAN and type the same command on cmd from another computer while server on my computer is running fine it shows connection  failed.

Why is this happening ???

Edit : I am a begginer in networking. So plz help me understand what's going wrong.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost address.  you're only listening on the local interface.  you should listen on 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces (though that will only open it up to things that can reach the ethernet IP address) and then go from there.

Comment: So many basic fundamentals have been missed I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Can u provide me a link to a site which could explain me the basics of networking? Cause I had downloaded a PDF and was following it. And according to it this should work. We can't trust what's right or wrong on the web...

Answer (score 0):

Because you're binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of an address on an external interface. Only the local computer can connect to this address, which is why it's called the "loopback address".